# install libpq-dev broken on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: comerr-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install -f`, if that doesn't work run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`,  then try again

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could try install it from source code.
For libpq-dev, you must install PostgreSQL

That link show you how to install:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/installation.html